# Prove that L has four elements , the product of which is equal to the fourth power of an integer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

The set $L$ consists of 2003 integers , none of which has a prime divisor larger than $24$. Prove that $L$ has four elements , the product of which is equal to the fourth power of an integer.

Above question statement , can someone please explain in simple intuitive manner how pigeonhole principle is applied in the question and how can we prove that?

Comment: That‘s a rerun of a 1984. (Prague) or 1985 (Finland)  IMO problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember seeing a problem like this in a book of math puzzles, maybe it was *Coffeetime in Memphis* by Bollobás? Anyways, I remember the solution.

First, we prove that there exist *two* numbers, the product of which is a perfect *square*. There are $9$ primes less than 24, call them $p_1,\dots,p_9$, so each integer can be written as
$
p_1^{n_1}\dots p_{9}^{n_9}, 
$ where $n_i$ is a nonnegative integer for each $i\in \{1,\dots,9\}$.
Let us make $512=2^9$ pigeonholes, each labeled by a sequence of length nine whose entries are either "even" or "odd." Put each of the $2003$ numbers into the pigeonhole which describes its sequence of multiplicities $(n_1,\dots,n_9)$. Since there are many more pigeons than holes, there exist two numbers $x_1$ and $y_1$ in the same hole. You can then check that $x_1y_1$ has all even multiplcities in its prime factorization, so $x_1y_1$ is a perfect square.

Ok, but how does this help us? The next step is to remove $x_1$ and $y_1$, and return our attention to the remaining $2001$ integers. Note that $2001$ is still much greater than $512$, so we can still find a pair $x_2$ and $y_2$ for which $x_2y_2$ is a perfect square. Do this over and over again, for a total of $513$ times, resulting in a list of pairs
$$
(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_{513},y_{513})
$$
whose products are all perfect squares. Finally, apply the the same argument to the list  $$\sqrt{x_1y_1},\dots,\sqrt{x_{513}y_{513}}$$ to find two products whose product is a perfect square, say that they are $\sqrt{x_iy_i}$ and $\sqrt{x_jy_j}$. Since $\sqrt{x_iy_i}\cdot\sqrt{x_jy_j}$ is a perfect square, it follows $x_iy_ix_jy_j$ is a perfect fourth power.

We used the pigeonhole principle $514$ times, surely this is some kind of record!

Comment: Indeed, this lovely argument shows that $2003$ can be reduced to $3\cdot2^9+1=1537$. And it turns out that this is best possible! It's not hard to show that$$\big\{ m^4 p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_9^{r_9} \colon 1\le m\le 3,\, 0\le r_1\le 1,\, 0\le r_2\le 1,\, \dots,\, 0\le r_9\le 1 \big\}$$ is a set of $1536$ integers with no four elements that multiply to a fourth power.

Comment: @Mike Earnest - Thanks for the explanation but I am still struggling. My doubts are you said there are 512 pigeonholes and 2003 pigeons (integers) . but how we get 513 pairs when there are only 512 holes are available. My understanding goes like - Since there are 2003 integers and 512 pigeonholes , so there will be 512 pairs that completely satisfy the squares property. In this way we will eliminate 1024 integers out of 2003 and left with 979. Now out of this 979 integers and 512 pigeonholes we are able to get some what less than 512 value that will be perfect squares. Am i understanding right

Comment: Step 1: There are 2003 pigeons, and 512 holes. Therefore, there exist two pigeons in the same hole. Remove them as a pair.$\tag*{}$Step 2: There are 2001 pigeons, and 512 holes. Therefore, there exist two pigeons in the same hole. Remove them as a pair.$\tag*{}$$\vdots$$\tag*{}$Step 513. There are 1983 pigeons, and 512 holes. Therefore, there exist two pigeons in the same hole. Remove them as a pair.$\tag*{}$Final step: Take the 513 pairs from the previous steps (one from each step), and put them into 512 holes (using the square root of each product). There exists two pigeons in the same hole.

Comment: @isilia Typo in the last comment: "Step 513: there are 983 pigeons, and 512 holes." My last comment says in detail how the PHP is being applied, and why it is valid. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Mike Earnest - yes now it makes much sense. It amazes me that concept of php is so simple but when it comes to apply in the question I totally struggle. Is there a limit to number of qiestions we should attempt to totally cement the concept ..or there will always be at least one question in which even experts will struggle. Thanks anyways for your detailed answer

Comment: My advice: do not be discouraged if you were unable to solve this puzzle! This is the hardest PHP problem I’ve seen, and I was also not able to solve it, and I think many other experienced math people would be stumped as well

Comment: Can this be proven with linear algebra aproach?

Comment: @Mike Earnest I'm still not understanding why there is 983 pigeons in step 513. Shouldn't there be 2003-2(513) = 977 pigeons left? Also, is there a reason why we are stopping at 513? Since 513(2) = 1026, which means there are still a bunch of integers we haven't coupled together yet. Thanks!

Comment: @ Greg Martin Could you please explain why $3 \cdot 2^9 +1$?  Thanks!

Comment: @Oran (A) I got my arithmetic wrong, but you did as well. In step 513, there should be $2013 - {\bf 512}\cdot 2=979$ pigeons left, because there were $512$ previous steps. (B) We are stopping at 513, because that is all we need for the final step. There are 512 possible even/odd sequences, so we need 513 perfect squares to guarantee finding two whose square roots have the same even/odd sequences, which guarantees their product is a perfect fourth power.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks, that makes a lot more sense!